# In Qt4.8, add a QToolButton to a QMenu, the auto connect not work

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a QToolButton `button1` with a popup QMenu `menu`. I add another QToolButton `button2` into the `menu`. I have already defined the ObjectName. But the auto connect only works for `button1`, not `button2`.

For the main window

```cpp
QToolButton *button1 = new QToolButton();
button1->setObjectName("action1");
button1->setText("Save");

button1->setPopupMode(QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup);

QToolButton *button2 = new QToolButton();
button2->setObjectName("action2");
button2->setText("Save11");

QMenu *pMenu = new QMenu("Title");

QWidgetAction *ptoolButtonAction = new QWidgetAction(pMenu);
ptoolButtonAction->setDefaultWidget(button2);
pMenu->addAction(ptoolButtonAction);

button1 ->setMenu(pMenu);               

QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(this);
```

For the public slots part

```cpp
void MyClass::on_action1_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "action1 is clicked";
}


void MyClass::on_action2_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "action2 is clicked";
}
```

[button and menu look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhSo3.png)

In the terminal, when I click `button1` "Save", it shows the "action1 is clicked."
But when I click `button2` "Save1", it shows nothing.

**Update:**
Solve the issue by fixing

```cpp
QMenu *pMenu = new QMenu("Title", this);
```

also, the objectName should by unique, or the auto connect will fail for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your QObject hierarchy is flawed because you do not set an owner for the QToolButtons and the QMenu. `connectSlotsByName` walks the hierarchy to find objects and signals matching slots.